# Swift horizontal scrollview for view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I make an app with that scrolls horizontally through view controllers (not views because every view controller has some unique functionality).

Answer (score 1):

UIPageController will allow you to swipe between view controllers

Comment: More detailed please?

Comment: File > New Project > Page-Based App https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can do create custom page view controller:
Create scroll view, add view controllers into scrollView as subviews by setting the frames, so you can align one view controller next to another.

or you can use open source frameworks like

```
https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment
https://github.com/uias/Pageboy
```

Comment: Ok can you be more detailed? How will I set the frames? Cand you reply with some code